# Deleting a custom field field

Tags: custom-field

Is there a way to delete a custom field (in the sense of complete removal from WP database) without using a plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to phpMyAdmin, these steps should do the trick:

> Step 1: Login to your hosting account and launch myPHPadmin from the
>   cPanel, or equivalent, to access the WordPress database engine.
>
> Step 2: Enter a select SQL command to list all the meta keys you want
>   to remove. In this example, I want to find and eventually remove the
>   meta key dcssb_short_url.
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM 'wp_postmeta' where 'meta_key' = 'dcssb_short_url'
> ```
>
> Step 3: Once you are satisfied you’ve narrowed down the selection,
>   issue a delete SQL command to remove the rogue data
>
> ```
> DELETE * FROM 'wp-postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = 'dcssb_short_url'
> ```
>
> Step 4: Issue the same select SQL command again, to verify all the
>   offending records have been deleted.
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM 'wp_postmeta' where 'meta_key' = 'dcssb_short_url'
> ```
>
> If you get no results returned, it means that you successfully deleted
>   the records.

[Source](http://blog.grapii.com/2012/08/remove-custom-fields-from-wordpress-database-using-sql/)

Comment: DELETE * FROM... is not required, probably DELETE FROM... should suffice.